# javascript onclick window.open automatically fires

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem here is that whenever I open the page. the link is automatically opens, sometimes it opens 3 new windows without clicking the div

```
<div onTouchTap={window.open(a)}> TEST </div>
```

can you please provide your input? or suggest any other alternatives. by the way I am using ReactJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a function to the onTouchTap, you are actually executing `window.open(a)`.

You could do something like:

```
<div onTouchTap={() => window.open(a)}> TEST </div>
```

I describe a similar solution and some of the caveats in another answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37771414/350933

Answer (score 0):

It's very common mistake. There must be a function `() => {window.open(a)}` or `window.open.bind(null, a)` as onTouchTap handler, but you are trying to put function call here, so it calls every time when your div rendering