# OnClick event on React table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello first question and beginner React user here.  I followed this ([React - Triggering click event on table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771316/react-triggering-click-event-on-table-row/37771414) ) example to have an onClick event on a React table but the first issue is I receive a warning in Visual Studio Code that Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './gridStyle.css';

class Grid extends React.Component {

    onClickHandler = () => {
        const song = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
        console.log('We need to get the details for ', song);
    }

    renderResultRows(data) {
        return data.map((coord, index) =>
            // anon func maintains scope!
            // Pass in a function to our onClick, and make it anon
            // to maintain scope.  The function body can be anything
            // which will be executed on click only.  Our song value
            // is maintained via a closure so it works.
            (
                // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
                <tr key={index} data-item={coord} onClick={this.onClickHandler}>
                    <td data-title="cc">{coord.lat},{coord.lon}</td>
                    <td data-title="ic" />
                    <td data-title="dlat" />
                    <td data-title="dlon" />
                </tr>
            )); // no need to bind with anon function
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Coords passed in from Accuracy Calculator :', this.props.coords);
       return (
            <div className="grid">
                <table id="table0">
                    {this.renderResultRows(this.props.coords)}
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put e in your function

In your onClickHandler, add e in the parameter.

```
onClickHandler = (e) => {
   const song = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
   console.log('We need to get the details for ', song);
    
}
```

I hope it fixes your issue

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass the onClickHandler param as e,
refer below code.

```
import React from 'react';
import './gridStyle.css';

class Grid extends React.Component {

    onClickHandler = (e) => {
        const song = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
        console.log('We need to get the details for ', song);
    }

    renderResultRows(data) {
        return data.map((coord, index) =>
            // anon func maintains scope!
            // Pass in a function to our onClick, and make it anon
            // to maintain scope.  The function body can be anything
            // which will be executed on click only.  Our song value
            // is maintained via a closure so it works.
            (
                // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
                <tr key={index} data-item={coord} onClick={this.onClickHandler}>
                    <td data-title="cc">{coord.lat},{coord.lon}</td>
                    <td data-title="ic" />
                    <td data-title="dlat" />
                    <td data-title="dlon" />
                </tr>
            )); // no need to bind with anon function
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Coords passed in from Accuracy Calculator :', this.props.coords);
       return (
            <div className="grid">
                <table id="table0">
                    {this.renderResultRows(this.props.coords)}
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change...

```
  onClickHandler = () => {
    const song = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
    console.log('We need to get the details for ', song);
}
```

To

```
onClickHandler = (e) => {
    const song = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
    console.log('We need to get the details for ', song);
}
```

To prevent the error which you are getting. You can read more about the event object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a click event, an event object is passed as an argument to the handler. Just define `e` (you can name it anything...e is just a convention) as an argument to be consumed in the function, so that you can access properties (like target) on it.

```
 onClickHandler = (e) => {
     const song = e.target.getAttribute('data-item');
     console.log('We need to get the details for ', song);
 }
```

Hope this helps !